# Special permutations of $ \{ 1, 2, \cdots, 3k + 1 \} $

Tags: probability

> **Problem.** A random permutation of $ \{ 1, 2, 3, \cdots, 3k + 1 \} $ is written. What is the probability that the sum of the first $j$ terms is not divisible by $3$, for all $ j \in \{ 1, 2, \cdots, 3k + 1 \} $? Find a closed form.

Note: I have solved the above problem already. I am simply sharing & looking for some nice solutions here $-$ seeing if the Math.SE community comes up with some more creative solutions.

Comment: Is the question to calculate the probability that (simultaneously) *each* sum of an initial $j$ terms is not divisible by 3, or rather to get closed forms for each of the individual probabilities, one for every $j$ from 1 to $3k+1$?

Comment: @coffeemath The former. For example, the answer for $ k = 1 $ would be $\frac{1}{6}$ because only $ \{ 1, 4, 3, 2 \} $, $ \{ 1, 4, 2, 3, \} $, $ \{ 4, 1, 3, 2 \} $, and $ \{ 4, 1, 2, 3 \} $ out of the $24$ permutations.

Comment: One reason not to attack this sort of question is that it is annoying to be told afterwards, "yes, that was the way I did it."

Comment: @AhaanRungta In your comment, I think you are missing the permutations $\{1,3,4,2\}$ and $\{4,3,1,2\}$, and the answer should be $\frac14$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the entries in the permutations are colored blue, red or green, according to whether they are congruent to $1,2$ or $3$ (mod $3$). Then a permutation will be valid if and only if its first entry isn't green, and when the green entries are removed, the remaining ones start with a blue, followed by the alternating pattern blue, red, blue, red $\dots$

To choose such a permutation, you can choose the green entries in $\binom{3k}{k}$ ways, assign the other colors in just one way, then permute the numbers in each color in $(k+1)!$, $k!$, and $k!$ ways. Thus, the probability of a valid permutation is
$$
\frac{\binom{3k}kk!\cdot k!\cdot(k+1)!}{(3k+1)!}=\frac{k!\cdot(k+1)!}{(3k+1)\cdot(2k)!}=\frac{k+1}{(3k+1)\cdot\binom{2k}{k}}
$$

Comment: In this coloring there is one more blue entry than red or green. So it looks like it *must* start with a blue, in order that there be the same number of blues and reds to fill out the positions beyond the first alternately, after ignoring the $k$ greens. However that does not change the resulting count you've given. (+1)